# d3.js force collapsible graph - input data is object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, d3.js

I was trying to make a force collapsible graph similar to http://jsfiddle.net/skysigal/wx1rvahw/

In the jsfiddle example, data is in .json format

Suppose I have my data as an object array:

```
var data = [
   { "name" : "C", "parent":"A", "size": 50},
   { "name" : "A", "parent":"null", "size": 75 },
   { "name" : "J", "parent":"C", "size": 25 },
   { "name" : "N", "parent":"C", "size": 25 }, 
   { "name" : "T", "parent":"C", "size": 25 }
];
```

Is there any way I can convert this array to the json format required by the graph?

Comment: you need to format you data as required by graph basicallly you can loop though data or you can ask server guy to send it as you require it

Answer (score 1):

Use a recursive function to convert the flat JSON to hierarchical JSON.

**Sample code:**

```js
var data = [{
  "name": "C",
  "parent": "A",
  "size": 50
}, {
  "name": "A",
  "parent": "null",
  "size": 75
}, {
  "name": "J",
  "parent": "C",
  "size": 25
}, {
  "name": "N",
  "parent": "C",
  "size": 25
}, {
  "name": "T",
  "parent": "C",
  "size": 25
}];

var flare = {};

var root = data.filter(function(d){ return d.parent=="null"; })[0];
flare =  root;
flare.children = [];

findChildren(flare,root.name);
var idx = 1;
function findChildren(tree, name){      
  data.forEach(function(d, i) { 
     if(d.parent==name){       
       tree.children.push(d);     
       d.children = [];
       findChildren(d, d.name);
     }
  });  
  idx++;
  delete tree.parent;
  if(tree.children.length==0)
     delete tree.children;
  if(idx==data.length)
     return;
}

console.log(flare);

document.write(JSON.stringify(flare));
```

**Updated Fiddle:**

```js
var flatData = [{
  "name": "C",
  "parent": "A",
  "size": 5000
}, {
  "name": "A",
  "parent": "null",
  "size": 7500
}, {
  "name": "J",
  "parent": "C",
  "size": 6500
}, {
  "name": "N",
  "parent": "C",
  "size": 5500
}, {
  "name": "T",
  "parent": "C",
  "size": 6500
}];

var data = {};

var root = flatData.filter(function(d){ return d.parent=="null"; })[0];
data =  root;
data.children = [];

findChildren(data,root.name);

var idx = 1;
function findChildren(tree, name){      
  flatData.forEach(function(d, i) { 
     if(d.parent==name){       
       tree.children.push(d);     
       d.children = [];
       findChildren(d, d.name);
     }
  });  
  idx++;
  delete tree.parent;
  if(tree.children.length==0)
     delete tree.children;
  if(idx==flatData.length)
     return;
}

//Notes:
// Src: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1093130
//Notes:
// * Each dom element is using 
//   children to store refs to expanded children
//   _children to store refs to collapsed children
//* It's using both a tree and a graph layout.

//root 
var g = {
    data: null,
    force:null
};

$(function () {

    //use a global var for the data:
    g.data = data;


    var width = 960,
        height = 500;

    //Create a sized SVG surface within viz:
    var svg = d3.select("#viz")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);


    g.link = svg.selectAll(".link"),
    g.node = svg.selectAll(".node");

    //Create a graph layout engine:
    g.force = d3.layout.force()
        .linkDistance(80)
        .charge(-120)
        .gravity(0.05)
        .size([width, height])
    //that invokes the tick method to draw the elements in their new location:
    .on("tick", tick);



    //Draw the graph:
    //Note that this method is invoked again
    //when clicking nodes:
    update();


});







//invoked once at the start, 
//and again when from 'click' method
//which expands and collapses a node.

function update() {

    //iterate through original nested data, and get one dimension array of nodes.
    var nodes = flatten(g.data);

    //Each node extracted above has a children attribute.
    //from them, we can use a tree() layout function in order
    //to build a links selection.
    var links = d3.layout.tree().links(nodes);

    // pass both of those sets to the graph layout engine, and restart it
    g.force.nodes(nodes)
        .links(links)
        .start();

    //-------------------
    // create a subselection, wiring up data, using a function to define 
    //how it's suppossed to know what is appended/updated/exited
    g.link = g.link.data(links, function (d) {return d.target.id;});

    //Get rid of old links:
    g.link.exit().remove();

    //Build new links by adding new svg lines:
    g.link
        .enter()
        .insert("line", ".node")
        .attr("class", "link");

    // create a subselection, wiring up data, using a function to define 
    //how it's suppossed to know what is appended/updated/exited
    g.node = g.node.data(nodes, function (d) {return d.id;});
    //Get rid of old nodes:  
    g.node.exit().remove();
    //-------------------
    //create new nodes by making groupd elements, that contain circls and text:
    var nodeEnter = g.node.enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .on("click", click)
        .call(g.force.drag);
    //circle within the single node group:
    nodeEnter.append("circle")
        .attr("r", function (d) {return Math.sqrt(d.size) / 10 || 4.5;});
    //text within the single node group:
    nodeEnter.append("text")
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .text(function (d) {
        return d.name;
    });
    //All nodes, do the following:
    g.node.select("circle")
        .style("fill", color); //calls delegate
    //-------------------
}


// Invoked from 'update'.
// The original source data is not the usual nodes + edge list,
// but that's what's needed for the force layout engine. 
// So returns a list of all nodes under the root.
function flatten(data) {
    var nodes = [],
        i = 0;
    //count only children (not _children)
    //note that it doesn't count any descendents of collapsed _children 
    //rather elegant?
    function recurse(node) {
        if (node.children) node.children.forEach(recurse);
        if (!node.id) node.id = ++i;
        nodes.push(node);
    }
    recurse(data);

    //Done:
    return nodes;
}



//Invoked from 'update'
//Return the color of the node
//based on the children value of the 
//source data item: {name=..., children: {...}}
function color(d) {
    return d._children ? "#3182bd" // collapsed package
    :
    d.children ? "#c6dbef" // expanded package
    :
        "#fd8d3c"; // leaf node
}






// Toggle children on click by switching around values on _children and children.
function click(d) {
    if (d3.event.defaultPrevented) return; // ignore drag
    if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d.children = null;
    } else {
        d.children = d._children;
        d._children = null;
    }
    //
    update();
}





//event handler for every time the force layout engine
//says to redraw everthing:
function tick() {
    //redraw position of every link within the link set:
    g.link.attr("x1", function (d) {
        return d.source.x;
    })
        .attr("y1", function (d) {
        return d.source.y;
    })
        .attr("x2", function (d) {
        return d.target.x;
    })
        .attr("y2", function (d) {
        return d.target.y;
    });
    //same for the nodes, using a functor:
    g.node.attr("transform", function (d) {
        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    });
}
```

```css
.node circle {
    cursor: pointer;
    stroke: #3182bd;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
.node text {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
    pointer-events: none;
    text-anchor: middle;
}
line.link {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #9ecae1;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="viz" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON.stringify.

The JSON.stringify() method converts a JavaScript value to a JSON string, optionally replacing values if a replacer function is specified, or optionally including only the specified properties if a replacer array is specified.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify